# gsvideo cant play video on pcduino with processing

Tags: ubuntu, audio, processing, javasound

I installed processing on pcduino and also installed GSVideo version 1.0.0

When I run a video I get the following error

```
cannot connect to server socket err = no such file or directory 
cannot connect to server socket  
jack server is not running or canot be started
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong?

I do not have jackd installed because pulseaudio is already installed and running.